# Can't access MySQL from Glassfish pool

Tags: mysql, jdbc, glassfish, xampp

I have a connection pool created by following a  [tutorial](http://computingat40s.wordpress.com/how-to-setup-a-jdbc-connection-in-glassfish/). Also there is MySQL created from XAMPP, running on port 3036. 
Connection pool attributes are:

```
user       admin
password   admin
URL        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3036/test2
```

In my.ini of MySQL I added

```
[client] 
user=admin
database=test2
password       = admin
port            = 3036
```

But when I try to ping, I catch an error:

> Ping Connection Pool failed for Test2. The connection could not be
>   allocated: Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES)

What's wrong with settings?

Comment: And of course your user have sufficient privileges on that db?

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie in SQL. Where can I specify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your mssql shell as root and try to execute:

```
GRANT ALL ON test2.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
```

maybe this would help.

Comment: At first it didn't work. But after I checked >mysql status, and it was shown to me that server runs in 3306 port (but I put 3036 port in my.ini, and XAMPP shows that MySQL runs at 3036). So I changed port in pool attributes and it worked. Thanks!

But how it possible that real port is different from port that I specified?